# import error with pygame when running a sample game

Tags: python, pygame

I just begin study about pygame module and download a sample program.
When I run the program, the py shell returns the following text.

```
File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 95, in <module>

    from pygame.base import *

builtins.ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 not valid Win32...
```

Anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this error usually means you don't have the correct version of the module for your architecture downloaded.

If your OS is 32-bit and you're using 32-bit python, you need 32-bit pygame; but if your OS is 64-bit and you're using 64-bit python you need 64-bit pygame.

64-bit versions can be found [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame).

Comment: I am not sure whether my python is 32-bit or not. How can I check it

Comment: You can find out how to determine this here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html#cross-platform. Something like `import platform; platform.architecture()`.

Comment: Cool! It makes sense. My wing IDE doesn't support my system language so the error report are just some blocks.. Anyway thank you so much